# SQLite table not created in CLion with sqlite3_exec

Tags: c++, sqlite, clion

I am trying to connect to a SQLite database and to create a table in CLion,but it doesn't appear, although I get the "query executed" message.
My code:

Database.h:

```
class Database {
    sqlite3 *database;
    char * db_error;
    int status;
public:
    Database();
    bool OpenDatabase(const char *);
    bool ExecuteQuery(const std::string &);
    void CloseDatabase();

};
```

Server.cpp:

```
void Server::Start() {
database.OpenDatabase("application.db");
database.ExecuteQuery("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (username VARCHAR(16), password VARCHAR(32))");
}
```

Database.cpp:

```
bool Database::OpenDatabase(const char *filename) {
    if(sqlite3_open(filename,&database) !=SQLITE_OK) {
        cout<<"Unable to open database\n";
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
bool Database::ExecuteQuery(const std::string & query) {
    if(sqlite3_exec(database, query.c_str(), callback,0, &db_error)!=SQLITE_OK){
        cout<<"Couldn't execute following query: "<<query<<endl;
        sqlite3_free(db_error);
        return false;
    }
    cout<<"Query executed\n";
    return true;

}
```

I don't get any error message, it seems like the table is created (output is "Query executed"), but it doesn't show up in the Database section:
[check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgFXf.png)

My data source properties are the following:
[properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZODv.png)

Am I missing something?

Comment: My guess is you are looking at a different database file.

Comment: Yes, I was not setting up the IDE properly,  had to specify also the path to the db file created. Thank you! Took me a while to figure it out...